# new line in xml file

Tags: html, xml, jsp

I'm trying to open an xml file using jsp file.
I can open the file but for some reason I cant see breaks between the text showing.
I try'ed using 
 , [[CDATA]] , lyrics, <br> and all kind of things from the web but the text still appear in one line without breaks.
I followed this link  :  [Line Break in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986297/line-break-in-xml)
and all the suggestions in it but I still cant fix it.
I probably have a problem in my jsp code and not in the xml file but I just do'nt know what it is
I add my xml file and jsp in here :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="cd_catalog.css"?>
    <quiz>
    <question type="multichoice"  >
<name>
    <text>Name of question </text> 
</name>
<questiontext format="html">
    <text>What is the answer to this question?</text>
</questiontext>
<answer fraction="100">
    <text>The correct answer</text>
    <feedback><text>Correct!</text></feedback>
</answer>
<answer fraction="0">
    <text>A distractor</text>
    <feedback><text>Ooops!</text></feedback>
</answer>
    <answer fraction="0">
    <text>Another distractor</text>
    <feedback><text>Ooops!</text></feedback>
    </answer>
    <shuffleanswers>1</shuffleanswers>
    <single>true</single>
    <answernumbering>abc</answernumbering>
    </question>
    </quiz>
```

and this is the jsp file :

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/xml"
    %><%@ page import="java.io.*"
    %><%
    //dump out the file
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("questions.xml"));
    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine())!=null){
    out.print(line);
    }
    in.close();
    %>
```

could someone help me ? thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you just print out xml in html it'll try to interpret the tags as tags.  You need to escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the content-type to text/html and use CDATA with BR for newlines

Comment: thanks a lot.. changing the content type make it possible to work with <br \>