# JAXB unmarshal deletes newline

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a string with newlines in an attribute parameter :

```
<rule-parameter formattingMethod="NO_FORMATTING_METHOD" type="String" value="Hello,      
My name is luba.   
How are you?"/>
```

When I unmarshal this xml the object that I get for this property the string is in one line.

What should I do so the java property will also have newline in the string ?

Comment: Try to put the text in CDATA or maybe <br /> elements. Take a look on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986297/line-break-in-xml

Answer (score 3):

An XML parser (including JAXB) will not preserve a newline in an XML attribute.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends

You will need to move this content to an XML element instead.

Comment: The linked section does not mention anything about not preserving newlines. It only specifies that multiple carriage return (+ line feed) characters are normalized to a single line feed character.