# XML: Concatenate string and line break

Tags: xml, newline, string-concatenation

I want to write a simple message with a line break in the middle.  I know that in Java you can  do something like the following:

```
"Hey, this is a message" + \n + "...and this is the rest of it on a new line"
```

How can I do the same in XML?  Can I use the \n escape character or do I use the html line break?

I would like to add a message to the following element in the `ObjectValue` attribute:

```
<EnterValue ScreenName="" ObjectName="EMAIL_MESSAGE" ObjectValue=""/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line Break in XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986297/line-break-in-xml)

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: not precisely a duplicate - the cited question aims at inserting content of xml elements into html, the latter requiring a  markup representation of a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the numrical entity representation of xml: `&#x<hex code of char>;`, eg `&#x0a;`,`&#x0d;`  for a LF, CR, respectively.

note that this method works without regard to the character set and/or encoding being used as the byte range `0x00 - 0x7f` is shared by all encodings (roughly speaking at least. ebcdic will be different. but the dichotomy between unicode encodings vs. byte-oriented charsets will be covered).

Comment: I tried doing something like this `"Message 1 &#x0d; Message 2"` but it is still on the same line.  How should it be formatted?

Comment: try `&#x0a;`, `&#x0d;&#x0a;` at first. which application will display your xml data?

Comment: It's being displayed in IE9.

Comment: So, by copying exactly what you had, I got `"Message 1 [new line] , [new line] Message 2`

Comment: Alright, I got the desired results with just `&#x0d;&#x0a;`.  Thanks!  This seems kind of like a hack or workaround.  Is there another way?

Comment: @Keven: no, it's no hack but in the specs.