# Add a line break in the label of customUI.xml

Tags: xml, vba

I would like the button of `Add/Edit Citation` to show as

```
Add/Edit

Citation
```

instead of

```
Add/Edit Citation
```

in the ribbon of Word

the file is an xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="ZoteroTab" getLabel="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroTabLabel" insertBeforeMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="ZoteroGroup" image="zoteroz16" label="Zotero">
          <button id="InsertZoteroCitationButton" label="Add/Edit Citation" size="large" image="addEditZoteroCitation" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonAddEditCitation" supertip="Insert a new citation, or edit the citation at the current cursor position"/>
          <button id="InsertZoteroNoteButton" label="Add Note" size="large" image="addZoteroNote" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonAddNote" supertip="Insert a new note at the current cursor position"/>
          <button id="InsertZoteroBibliographyButton" label="Add/Edit Bibliography" size="large" image="addEditZoteroBibliography" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonAddEditBibliography" supertip="Insert a new bibliography, or edit the existing bibliography, at the current cursor position"/>
          <button id="ZoteroSetDocPrefs" label="Document Preferences" image="setZoteroDocPrefs-small" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonSetDocPrefs" supertip="Change the citation style or locale"/>
          <button id="RefreshZotero" label="Refresh" image="RefreshZotero" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonRefresh" supertip="Update all citations to reflect changes"/>
          <button id="ZoteroRemoveCodes" label="Unlink Citations" image="ZoteroRemoveCodes" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonRemoveCodes" supertip="Remove all Zotero field codes and unlink from Zotero library"/>
          <!-- <button id="InsertZoteroCitationButtonSmall" visible="false" label="Add/Edit Citation" image="addEditZoteroCitation-small" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonAddEditCitation" supertip="Insert a new citation, or edit the citation at the current cursor position"/>
        <button id="InsertZoteroBibliographyButtonSmall" visible="false" label="Add/Edit Bibliography" size="large" image="addEditZoteroBibliography-small" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonAddEditBibliography" supertip="Insert a new bibliography, or edit the existing bibliography, at the current cursor position"/>
          <button id="ZoteroSetDocPrefsLarge" visible="false" label="Document Preferences" size="large" image="setZoteroDocPrefs" onAction="ZoteroRibbon.ZoteroRibbonSetDocPrefs" supertip="Change the citation style or locale"/> -->
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I noticed this thread [Line Break in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986297/line-break-in-xml), and `&lt;br&gt;` `\n`, `\n\n` 
were tested, and it didn't work.

Any ideas, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a line break in the button's label, use `&#13;` eg `label="One&#13;Two"`

Comment: Thanks, it did not work either in WPS Office. It showed OneTwo, however it works in Word ribbon.

Comment: Your question asks how to do this in Word, not in WPS Writer, so would seem the answer is valid? Suggest asking another question for how to do this in WPS?

Comment: ok. what `&#13;` means